# Feller: "Since $U_{\zeta} (\infty) = \infty$ the exponent is necessarily $\leq \zeta$"

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is from Feller's 'Introduction to Probability' (Vol. 2), page 284. I have a function:

$$U_{\zeta} (x) = \int_0^x y^{\zeta} dF(y)$$

where $F$ is a cumulative distribution function and $\zeta > 0$. He first supposes that,

$$U_{\zeta} (x) \sim x^{\rho} L(x)$$

for some $\rho$ (where $L$ is slowly varying - that is, for any $x > 0$, $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{L(tx)}{L(t)} = 1$). The goal is to establish conditions on the exponent $\rho$. Feller states that $\rho \leq \zeta$ *because* $U_{\zeta} (\infty) = \infty$ however I don't see how this is true or can be shown to be true.

I first tried to integrate by parts on $U_{\zeta}$ and get the following:

$$U_{\zeta} (x) = F(x)x^{\zeta} - \int_0^x F(y) y^{\zeta - 1} dy \sim x^{\rho} L(x)$$

But not sure whether this helps or not. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the fact that $U_{\zeta} (\infty) = \infty$ would imply that $\rho \leqslant \zeta$ is a mystery to me, but, to prove the latter, one can note that, for every nonnegative $x$, $$U_{\zeta} (x) = \int_0^x y^{\zeta} dF(y)\leqslant\int_0^x x^{\zeta} dF(y)=x^\zeta F(x)\leqslant x^\zeta$$ hence the assumption that $$U_{\zeta} (x) \sim x^{\rho} L(x)$$ indeed implies that $$x^{\rho} L(x)\leqslant 2x^\zeta$$ when $x\to\infty$, in particular, $$\rho\leqslant\zeta$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. This has helped me to understand the logic of it all.

Comment: What about if we consider the integral $\int_x^{\infty} y^{\zeta} dF(y)$? Does this share the same property?

Comment: Which property exactly?

Comment: Sorry I just meant that the exponent in this case is also less than $\zeta$?

Comment: ??? $ $ $ $ $ $